# Get english version of localized string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslocalizedstring

I have method that I set NSUserDefaults to play a song based on the english version. I'm currently translating it all for other languages, but since the alarm is based on the NSUserDefaults object. This should make more sense:

```
- (void)applySoundNameAndSaveSoundToNSUserDefaults {
    [self.audioPlayer stop];

    NSString *soundName = self.soundNameLabel.text;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:soundName forKey:@"AlarmSound"];
}
```

So as you can see if the cells label is localized, it will put the language version of that name in NSUserDefaults, if i do it this way, which I don't want to.

This is how I play it:

```
self.alarmSound = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"AlarmSound"];

- (void) fireLocalNotification {
   NSString *notificationSound;
   notificationSound = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.alarmSound];
   notificationSound = [notificationSound stringByAppendingString:@".caf"];

   UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
   localNotification.soundName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", notificationSound];
}
```

This posses a problem because my sound.caf file in the main bundle is named in the english format. So how do I get the english version of 'self.soundNameLabel.text' when it's localized?

---

**EDIT** I've found this in the docs: `initWithFormat:locale:` which is exactly what i'm looking for. But i've read that it's not autoreleased so I don't know if it's something I should use. Also, I get errors for something like 'string is not literal string' when using it

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Just don't base program behavior on strings displayed to the user. I am pretty sure you can keep the necessary information in a better form than localized texts.

Answer (score 0):

Jteve,

I would probably do it with a simple verification. You could use other ways to solve your problem but that would mean that you have to change all your code. Here's what I would do (Not recommended tho):

```
- (void)applySoundNameAndSaveSoundToNSUserDefaults {

    [self.audioPlayer stop];

    NSString *soundName = self.soundNameLabel.text;

    //You know your translation value and your original English String so:

    if ([soundName isEqualToString:@"SpanishString1"] || [soundName isEqualToString:@"GermanString1"]) {
       soundName = @"EnglishString1";
    } else if ([soundName isEqualToString:@"GermanString2"]) {
       soundName = @"EnglishString2";
    }

 //Multiple if conditions in case you have more than one .caf

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:soundName forKey:@"AlarmSound"];

}
```

This way the

```
 - (void) fireLocalNotification
```

method will be unaffected

I strongly recommend to AVOID AT ALL COST to create algorithm logic based on localization. Your code should work flawlessly on any language as that should be just cosmetic.

I hope this works. There are other ways to do it, but this is the easiest way to avoid changing your whole methods.

Comment: I would like to avoid this, I was hoping there would be an easier API friendly method that I wouldn't have to create a conditional if statement, as I have a lot of languages & ___A LOT___ of sound names (something like 22) so  that would be a lot of if statements

Comment: You could use a tag on your souneNameLabel and simply name your .caf's from 1 to 22. and you AVOID ALL localization @JteveSobs

Comment: theres only 1 label though (the label changes depending on the selection) so thats a good idea, but wouldn't work. the tag would always equal 1 or whatever I set it to. I was just wondering if there is a way to get the reverse of the localized string

Comment: Is it a TableView or something like that? Even if it is a label in a ViewController and that view controller is showed by different buttons/actions. You can pass the tag from the Cell or the button or even as a counter. An dynamically change the tag of the UILabel depending on the selection origin

Comment: that is an option, but doesn't answer the question. I would like to keep it consistent so when people look for this answer in the future they get one specific to the question. Thank you for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this just by creating a dictionary of Keys/Objects from the main bundle since thats where the localized strings are, and then get the key for the object(which will always be english since thats my base):

```
NSString *localizedSoundName = self.soundNameLabel.text;

NSDictionary *localizedDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Localizable" ofType:@"strings"]];
NSArray *tempArray = [localizedDict allKeysForObject:localizedSoundName];
NSString *englishSoundName = [tempArray objectAtIndex:0];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:englishSoundName forKey:@"AlarmSound"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should rework your model such that the user-facing UI strings are separated from the underlying filenames. For instance, imagine a model object representing a Sound, it would have a displayName (shown to the user, localized) and a fileName (which is passed to AVAudioPlayer). Regardless of what localisation the app is in, the fileName always corresponds to the correct file.

Comment: This is exactly my case benjamin? the displayName (show to the user, localized) is for example @"Polizei", and the fileName (which is passed to AVAudioPlayer) is Police.caf which is why I need the english version. I don't have an 'objectAtIndex' to reference or else this question wouldn't even be asked, it's a case of only getting it from the label